# Hibernate Code Generation and @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Please consider the following mySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE storeman.user (
    id              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    display_name    VARCHAR(50),
    password        CHAR(32),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX    (email)
);

CREATE TABLE storeman.user_preferences (
    id              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    notify_login    BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,

    PRIMARY KEY     (id),
    CONSTRAINT      fk_user_preferences FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

As you may see there's a one-to-one relationship between the two tables.
When running the Hibernate Code Generator, I get the follwoing (relevant part only)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "storeman", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public UserPreferences getUserPreferences(){
        return this.userPreferences;
    };
...
}
```

The issue with that is when I save the User entity, the linked UserPreferences is not saved automartically. Solving this is easy:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
public UserPreferences getUserPreferences(){
    return this.userPreferences;
};
```

However, If for any reason I will have to re run the Hibernate Code Generator again, the `@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})` will be gone, and this is dangerous as I'm relying on the fact that linkled tables are automatically saved in my code.
So the question is: is there a way to modify mySQL script on top so that, while running hibernate reverse engineering code generation, the @Cascade annotation is automatically added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mySql physical table doesn't say anything about cascading other then the foreign key. Only it can add ON DELETE CASCADE ON DELETE UPDATE.

Then you run Hibernate Code Generator, CascadeType and @Cascade definitions are not translated into DDL

Try to use jpa annotations much as possible.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
public UserPreferences getUserPreferences(){
    return this.userPreferences;
};
```